# JSP servlet mapping

Tags: jsp, java-ee-6, servlet-3.0, url-mapping

With introduction of [Servlet 3.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/14/introduction-to-servlet-3.html) we could map servlets to URL patterns using [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) and ommiting mapping within web.xml.

I wonder if there some intstructions or special tags allowing mapping jsp to URL in page code without declaring servlets in web.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no facility like that.

Best what you could do is to hide the JSP in `/WEB-INF` (so that it can never be requested directly by URL) and just create a servlet which forwards to that JSP and finally map it on the desired URL pattern. It's fairly easy:

```
@WebServlet("/foo")
public class FooServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/foo.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

This way the JSP in `/WEB-INF/foo.jsp` is available by `http://localhost:8080/context/foo`. You could abstract it further to a single servlet for a bunch of JSPs using the [front controller pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297).